# Baldwin MCX-88 makes cracking sound

Tags: repair, speakers

How can I repair my Baldwin MCX-88 that makes a cracking sound when I press any of the keys? The odd part is that the sounds continues even after I left up on the key.

Is there anywhere that I can find a manual (owners or technical) on this electric organ?

I am assuming that it has something to do with the speakers going bad, but I'm not sure why the sounds would continue after the key is released. The keys do bounce back up when they are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a blown speaker.  You can disassemble the keyboard and find the speakers and try to find a replacement that fits.  Remove the old speaker, and solder in the new one.  Crackling or fizzing or distorted sounds are almost always rips/tears/problems with the speaker cone.

Comment: I had that same hunch myself. I will take it apart and let you know what I find out. Do you know what voltage and amperage would run to the speakers? I have a multimeter and would like to test the power to the speakers as well.